# What is The most detailed Mathematical Methods for physics book?

Tags: resource-recommendations, linear-algebra

I am taking a course in Mathematical Physics Junior Level (Undergraduate). 
We are working from Arfken's "Mathematical Methods for physicists", but i am finding trouble with it specially in the determinants and matrices chapter, since it is not detailed enough. any suggestions for a more detailed book?

Comment: Arfken is a bit steep for juniors, but there is no consensus on a really great undergraduate text. A lot of programs use Boas (or at least they used to), but I often get the feeling that people think it is the best of the not particularly great choices.

Comment: The fact that this was flagged for closure as *primarily opinion based* somewhat reinforces my [proposal to make them all off-topic](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/7099/25301), but that's **not** currently the site policy (which is that they're on topic).

Comment: Well, if you want real details and deepness, perhaps is better to get a math book.